I cant reach image with using JSON file
My reactjs code fails to show the image from db.json.
Image information is loeaded but the image is not displayed.
See this screenshot of my page
What could be the cause?

I assume the image information is in the json file, not the js file, am I right?

I thought it could be pulled from the js file

and tried ../../img/clothing/etc.webp
and tried ../../img/giyim/etc.webp

I also tried to change file location (see screenshot of the file paths). But the images are still not loaded / displayed.
<div className="products">
          <div className="product-wrapper">
            {this.props.products.map((product) => (
              <div className="product" key={product.id}>
                <img src={product.image} alt={product.id}></img>
                {/* <div>{product.id}</div> */}
                <div>
                  <Link to={"/saveproduct/" + product.id}>
                    {product.productName}
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div>{product.unitPrice}</div>
                {/* <td>{product.quantityPerUnit}</td>
                <td>{product.unitsInStock}</td> */}
                <span>
                  <Button color="info" onClick={() => this.addToCart(product)}>
                    Sepet
                  </Button>
                </span>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "bicak1",
      "productName": "FleshEdge Bıçak N690 ... Suya Dayanıklı",
      "categoryId": 1,
      "unitPrice": "5699",
      "image": "img/giyim/soft-set2.webp",
      "quantityPerUnit": "30",
      "unitsInStock": "31"
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "categoryName": "Bıçaklar",
      "seoUrl": "bicaklar"
    }
  ]
}


Are my edits correct? Is this what you are asking? If in doubt a translator (deepl.com) might be of use.


Try adding a / before the path to the image. So, /img/giyim/soft-set2.webp in the db.json file.

It is better to use environment variables by adding the images in the public folder and use the %PUBLIC_URL% variable which will automatically include the path to the public directory. Have a look here - Using Public Folder


Also, as a general rule, you should store all your assets like fonts, images, etc in the public folder

I add / /img/giyim/soft-set2.webp like that and try add ./ ./img/giyim/soft-set2.webp both ways are not work. Thanks for your second suggestion I try to work like that but i need to show the picture first

OK, it's done, as you said, I changed the location of the image folder to public folder. img/bicaklar/b1.webp now it works like this.

If you use Image path directly in the src then it should be present in the public folder for example  <img src='./product.png' alt={product.id}></img>
, In this case product.png should be in public folder.
If you want to use image like this <img src={product} alt={product.id}></img> then first you need import it.
for example if image is in the ./assets/images folder you need to import like this import product from './assets/images/product.png'; and then you can use it directly like this <img src={product} alt={product.id}></img>
